# how to allow cross domain file download from google storage in angular5

Tags: angular, cross-domain, google-cloud-storage

We are using Videogular2 player (VG player) on our website. We would like to add subtitles to one of our videos, with our subtitle file (.vtt) stored in Cloud Storage.

When I give the link to that file to VG player, it returns the following error:

"Text track from origin 'https://storage.googleapis.com' has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access."

Please advise on how to resolve this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this situation is related to the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy (CORS)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin), that allows your application to perform requests to the Cloud Storage bucket even if it comes from a different origin, which in this case would be the VG player.

In this case, you should be able to set the [CORS configuration](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors) to your Cloud Storage bucket. For achieving this, what you have to do is run the following command, which will generate a JSON file with the CORS configuration for your bucket:

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://[YOUR-BUCKET]
```

After running this command, you should be able to use your VG player application to fetch the subtitles file from your storage bucket.